# How to reference a controller from a laravel nova action?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I am trying to create a simple action in my laravel nova app which exports a resource to pdf..

the controllers are in

```
app/http/controllers
```

when i try to use a controller inside my actions calling new blablaController.. it throws an error like

```
Class 'App\Nova\Actions\blablaController' not found
```

so, how do i say that my controller is in app/http/controllers ??

i have referenced my action in the controller like:

```
use App\Nova\Actions\BlaBla;
```

Comment: Add `use App\Http\Controllers\blablaController` on top of your action class & call it `new blablaController`

Comment: it was a bit stupid question, but thank you!